# Assymptotic expansion of fourier transform where stationary phase approximation fails

Tags: integration, asymptotics, fourier-transform

I would like to get the assymptotic expansion for large $t$ of the integral:

$\int_0^\infty dx \frac{1}{x \log(x)^2}e^{-i x t}$

I have tried the stationary phase methods, but i think it can not be applied for, because the first derivative is constant and the second one vanishes. Any hint?

Comment: i think the asymptotics of such an integral are discussed in bender and orszag's book on perturbative methods